# DataFrame - groupby and transform in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, average

I got a "Building a comprehensive set of Technical Indicators in Python for quantitative trading" code sample from:

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-comprehensive-set-of-technical-indicators-in-python-for-quantitative-trading-8d98751b5fb

However, groupby method (for Simple Moving Average-SMA) is resolved based on it's 'symbol' (AAPL or NFLX):

```
all_data['SMA_5'] = all_data.groupby('symbol')['Close'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(window = 5).mean())

all_data['SMA_15'] = all_data.groupby('symbol')['Close'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(window = 15).mean())
```

If I have my own DataFrame without the symbol column (only open, close, high, low and volume), is there a way to skip it and perform this method (together with mentioned transform method call)?
Calling the method this way seem to require it's symbol column.

Thank you!

I have tried erasing the ('symbol') requirement, however the method does not seem to respond to this type of call.
I would like to receive an SMA for a DataFrame that only have open, close, high, low and volume columns using groupby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to group by "symbol" and just want to apply the transformation on your whole data, just remove the whole groupby call:

```
all_data['SMA_5'] = all_data['Close'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(window = 5).mean())
```

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Repos\team-project\pages\data_page.py", line 25, in proccess_data
    sma.run(stock_data)
  File "d:\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Repos\team-project\libs\neural_networks\simple_moving_average.py", line 61, in run
    test_frame3['SMA_5'] = all_data['Close'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(window = 5).mean())

My 'test_frame3' have date, open, high, low, close and volume columns..

Comment: Please ignore the error, my implementation was wrong, your advice worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for 5 day moving average

```
all_data['SMA_5'] = all_data['column_name'].ewm(span=5).mean()
```

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Repos\team-project\pages\data_page.py", line 25, in proccess_data
    sma.run(stock_data)
  File "d:\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Repos\team-project\libs\neural_networks\simple_moving_average.py", line 61, in run
    test_frame3['SMA_5'] = all_data['Close'].ewm(span=5).mean()
raise ValueError("cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels")
cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels

Comment: Edit your question and add a sample of your data

Comment: Please ignore the error, my implementation was wrong, your advice worked. Thank you!